# Retrieve and set RecyclerView data from two different Firebase nodes

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

My main goal is to set a RecyclerView item as "favorited" based on a user's previous actions. I'm able to store and delete this data on click, but I'm having difficulty showing it in the right place at the right time.

I have two different nodes that I'm using for this to happen:

```
"quotes" : {
   "0" : {
      "Name" : "Foo",
      "Source" : "Bar" },
   "1" : {
      "Name" : "Foo",
      "Source" : "Bar" },
   "2" : {
      "Name" : "Foo",
      "Source" : "Bar" }
   },

"favorites" : {
   "blah@blah,com" : {
      "uid0" : "0"
      "uid1" : "2" }}}
```

So basically what I'm trying to do:
Show all the quotes in a RecyclerView, and if their ids show up in the favorites for that unique user, set it visually as favorited. I've included some code here that doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
private void bindHeart(final ItemHeartCardBinding binding) {
        if (inProgress) {
            animateProgress(binding);
        } else {
            binding.favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_state_list);
        }
        //Loop through users favorites to see if current item exists
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        String email = "";
        if (user != null) {
            email = user.getEmail();
            email = email.replace(".", ",");
        }

        final DatabaseReference favoriteRef = mRootRef.child("favorites/" + email);

        //quoteKeyStringResId is passed in here as each RecyclerView item is being created. It's the uid of each quote.
        final Query queryRef = favoriteRef.orderByValue().startAt(quoteKeyStringResId).endAt(quoteKeyStringResId);

        queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().equals(quoteKeyStringResId)) {
                    binding.favorite.setChecked(checked);
                } else {
                    binding.favorite.setChecked(!checked);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug through the [Firebase database samples](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android) and found a better way to model my data. Including all the relevant data in the same node allows me to query all at the same time and not have to worry about keeping RecyclerView items in the same order. Things aren't as shallow in this way, but I think that's okay:

```
"quotes" : {
   "0" : {
      "Name" : "Foo",
      "Source" : "Bar",
      //Moved this from a separate node into here
      "Favorites" : {
          //Each user will be listed if favorited, and removed if unfavorited, making it easy to track and get totals
          "userUid" : "true",
          "userUid4" : "true" }},
   "1" : {
      "Name" : "Foo",
      "Source" : "Bar" },
   "2" : {
      "Name" : "Foo",
      "Source" : "Bar",
      "Favorites" : {
          "userUid" : "true" }
   }}
```

Comment: I am surprised no one has answered this questions.  Of all the things in firebase the recycler view is especially difficult - with model/adapter/fragment or activity - three files for a simple list.. in php it is so easy....